How to Access and Modify wp-config.php via FTP on AWS, Backup WordPress Site, and Update Plugins
I need to:

Access the wp-config.php file via FTP (SSH) using Filezilla, WinSCP, or Ubuntu Linux on a VM.

Toggle the logic from define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true); to define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', false);.

Save the changes and reboot the AWS server.

Backup the theme and all data using the WP Data Migration tool (which we are currently paying for).

Update the WordPress core and all plugins.


Background
I work at a charity and handle UX and content support. Seven years ago, the developer who built our site restricted access, preventing us from editing the theme or updating plugins. Here are some key points for context:

The developer deliberately locked down our privileges.
Other developers have refused to help without proper access rights, suggesting a complete site rebuild instead.
The original development team offered to find the AWS key for a significant fee.

We need to regain access to our site to perform updates and backups without resorting to a costly rebuild.

AWS EC2 Management Console:


Set up inbound traffic for my IP, allowing all traffic and SSH in Security Groups.


Putty and PuttyGen:


Followed steps from this YouTube tutorial on managing WordPress files on AWS with FileZilla FTP.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoO0ca-UHUA

Created key pairs in AWS, converted .pem to .ppk file in PuttyGen, and configured settings in Putty.

Followed setup on Filezilla


enter image description here
enter image description here
Essentially I am not able to connect to the AWS instance.

I’m not certain what all we can really help you with. You need credentials to access the server, and possibly a firewall rule, but that’s not something we can help with. Do you have access to this server in AWS?

Hi Christ hanks for getting back to me - I have access to AWS via the browser i.e. ''https://eu-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/'' - and i can login and view the instance. It is me trying to access the instance via Filezilla to see the wordpress files...

To be very clear, you have admin access, right? So you can restart the instance and such? Also, SO is probably not the right place for this, I think Server Fault is probably more appropriate

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
